# Pasting HTML into CKEDITOR

Tags: ckeditor

How can you paste HTML directly into a CKEDITOR without clicking source? I can test that the settings support the tags I paste because it works if I paste after clicking "source." I've tried "full html" input type and my custom text input type.

But if I paste directly the code gets cleaned/converted.

For example this:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Louisiana has a chance to have a really great Governor in <a href="https://twitter.com/EddieRispone?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">@EddieRispone</a>. Auto insurance costs and taxes will be coming way down with Eddie, and your 2nd Amendment will be protected. Current Democrat governor has done a really poor job! VOTE EARLY FOR EDDIE!</p>&mdash; Donald J. Trump (@realDonaldTrump) <a href="https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1190694747716886528?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">November 2, 2019</a></blockquote>
```

renders as this (unless pasted into source):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the source button to EDIT the source code.
The code you're trying to put is only usable in html. So your script is going to read this as TEXT and not as HTML like you cant. You have to put it via the source code button.

Or you can use PHP to parse your document but it's not the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Is it possible to use a widget or custom widget to add in code without clicking the source button?

Comment: I think this plugin can do the work
https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/mediaembed
or
https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/Support/Solved-I-cant-embed-tweet-with-the-new-version-4.1.1

I've not tested it but it seems to be the right way to do it